# Does anyone know of an ASP.Net E-mail control/user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I'm implementing a messaging system in my program. It functions just like e-mail except that it is entirely contained within the system.

I was wondering if anyone has seen an e-mail control template that I could modify. It would have stuff like an inbox, message viewing and message sending parts.

I would just rewire the mail sending & receiving parts to my hook up to my tables.

Thanks!

Edit:

Ok I didn't realize I wrote so much. Make sure you credit Biff_MaGriff if you use this. :D
Tech is .net 3.5 with SubSonic 3.0

The rest is in my answer.

Should look like this in the end. (Minus all my cut outs)

[image]

web.config

```
<pages>
    <controls>
        ...
        <add tagPrefix="cc" tagName="MessageFolder" src="~/UserControls/Messages/MessageFolder/MessageFolder.ascx"/>
        <add tagPrefix="cc" tagName="MessageView" src="~/UserControls/Messages/MessageView/MessageView.ascx"/>
        <add tagPrefix="cc" tagName="MessageCompose" src="~/UserControls/Messages/MessageCompose/MessageCompose.ascx"/>
        <add tagPrefix="cc" tagName="MessageBox" src="~/UserControls/Messages/MessageBox/MessageBox.ascx"/>
        ...
    </controls>
<pages>
```

App_Code/IMessageFolder.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for IMessageFolder
/// </summary>
public interface IMessageFolder
{
    int? MessageID { get; }
}
```

App_Code/CustomDataViews.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CustomDataViews
/// </summary>
public class CustomDataViews
{
    //Subsonic db
    static VAC.Data.VACDB db = new VAC.Data.VACDB();

    public class MessageQuery
    {
        public class Message
        {
            public int MessageID { get; set; }
            public string FromUser { get; set; }
            public string ToUser { get; set; }
            public DateTime SentDate { get; set; }
            public string Subject { get; set; }
            public string Body { get; set; }
            public bool IsDeletedSender { get; set; }
            public bool IsDeletedRecipient { get; set; }
            public bool IsRead { get; set; }
        }

        public enum MailType { ReceivedMail, SentMail };

        public Message[] GetMessages(MailType mt, bool showDeleted)
        {
            List<Message> myMessages = new List<Message>();

            foreach (var v in (from m in db.Messages
                               where (mt == MailType.ReceivedMail ? m.ToUserID : m.FromUserID) == Common.CurrentUserID
                               && (showDeleted || !(mt == MailType.ReceivedMail ? m.IsDeletedRecipient : m.IsDeletedSender))
                               orderby m.SentDate descending
                               select m))
            {
                Message mess = new Message();
                mess.MessageID = v.MessageID;
                mess.FromUser = (from u in db.Users where u.UserID == v.FromUserID select u.UserName).First();
                mess.ToUser = (from u in db.Users where u.UserID == v.ToUserID select u.UserName).First();
                mess.SentDate = v.SentDate;
                mess.Subject = v.Subject;
                mess.Body = v.Body;
                mess.IsDeletedSender = v.IsDeletedSender;
                mess.IsDeletedRecipient = v.IsDeletedRecipient;
                mess.IsRead = v.IsRead;
                myMessages.Add(mess);
            }

            return myMessages.ToArray();
        }

        public Message GetMessage(int MessageID)
        {
            var myMessage = (from m in db.Messages where m.MessageID == MessageID select m);
            if (myMessage.Count() == 1)
            {
                var v = myMessage.First();
                Message mess = new Message();
                mess.MessageID = v.MessageID;
                mess.FromUser = (from u in db.Users where u.UserID == v.FromUserID select u.UserName).First();
                mess.ToUser = (from u in db.Users where u.UserID == v.ToUserID select u.UserName).First();
                mess.SentDate = v.SentDate;
                mess.Subject = v.Subject;
                mess.Body = v.Body;
                return mess;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

App_Code/Common.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Common
/// </summary>
public class Common
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the index of the column from the gridview. Returns -1 if not found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gv"></param>
    /// <param name="columnName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static public int GetColumnIndex(GridView gv, string columnName)
    {
        int returnMe = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (gv.Columns[i].HeaderText == columnName)
            {
                returnMe = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return returnMe;
    }

    //Colours for gridviews
    static public string BGColourRed = "#FF8888";
    static public string BGColourRedAlternate = "#FF0000";

    static public string BGColourBlue = "#AAAAFF";
    static public string BGColourBlueAlternate = "#4444FF";

    static public string BGColourGreen = "#2bf053";
    static public string BGColourGreenAlternate = "#27c319";

    static public string BGColourOrange = "#FFA365";
    static public string BGColourOrangeAlternate = "#FF6600";

    static public string NormalBGColour(object sender)
    {
        return "#" +
            ((GridView)sender).RowStyle.BackColor.R.ToString("X") +
            ((GridView)sender).RowStyle.BackColor.G.ToString("X") +
            ((GridView)sender).RowStyle.BackColor.B.ToString("X");
    }

    static public string AlternateBGColour(object sender)
    {
        return "#" +
            ((GridView)sender).AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor.R.ToString("X") +
            ((GridView)sender).AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor.G.ToString("X") +
            ((GridView)sender).AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor.B.ToString("X");
    }

    static public string SelectedBGColour(object sender)
    {
        string selectedBGColour = "#165EA9";

        if (!((GridView)sender).SelectedRowStyle.BackColor.IsEmpty)
        {
            selectedBGColour = "#" +
               ((GridView)sender).SelectedRowStyle.BackColor.R.ToString("X") +
               ((GridView)sender).SelectedRowStyle.BackColor.G.ToString("X") +
               ((GridView)sender).SelectedRowStyle.BackColor.B.ToString("X");
        }
        return selectedBGColour;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gridview RowDataBound extension.
    /// Allows row selection by clicking on a row and highlights the row in yellow on the mouse hover.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    static public void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.DataItemIndex == -1)
            return;

        //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", ((GridView)sender).Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference((GridView)sender, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString(), false));

        string selectedBGColour = SelectedBGColour(sender);
        string normalBGColour = NormalBGColour(sender);
        string alternateBGColour = AlternateBGColour(sender);

        ApplyStylingToRow(e.Row, selectedBGColour, normalBGColour, alternateBGColour);
    }

    static public void ApplyStylingToRow(GridViewRow row, string selectedBGColour, string normalBGColour, string alternateBGColour)
    {
        AppendAttribute(row, "onMouseOver",
               "this.style.cursor='pointer'; this.style.background='yellow';");
        AppendAttribute(row, "onMouseOut",
            "this.style.background='" + ((row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Selected) == DataControlRowState.Selected ? selectedBGColour :
            (row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Alternate) == DataControlRowState.Alternate ? alternateBGColour : normalBGColour) + "';");
    }


    static public void GridViewAddRowClick(GridView gv, GridViewRow row, bool isRender)
    {
        AppendAttribute(row, "onclick", gv.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(gv, "Select$" + row.RowIndex.ToString(), isRender) + ";");
        /*
        for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gv.Columns[i].HeaderText) && row.Cells.Count > 1)
                AppendAttribute(row.Cells[i], "onclick", gv.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(gv, "Select$" + row.RowIndex.ToString(), isRender) + ";");
         * */
    }

    static public void GridViewRowClick_Render(GridView gv)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                GridViewAddRowClick(gv, row, true);
        gv.Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(gv.UniqueID);
    }

        /// <summary>
    /// Hides a column on a gridview.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gv"></param>
    /// <param name="columnIndex"></param>
    static public void HideColumn(GridView gv, int columnIndex)
    {
        if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
            gv.HeaderRow.Cells[columnIndex].Style.Add("display", "none");
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                row.Cells[columnIndex].Style.Add("display", "none");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers javascript to be run.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="con"></param>
    /// <param name="script"></param>
    static public void RegisterStartupScript(object con, string script)
    {
        RegisterStartupScript((Control)con, script);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Capitalizes the beginning of strings
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strText"></param>
    public static string InitCap(string strText)
    {
        return new CultureInfo("en").TextInfo.ToTitleCase(strText.ToLower());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers javascript to be run.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="con"></param>
    /// <param name="script"></param>
    static public void RegisterStartupScript(Control con, string script)
    {
        ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(con.Page);
        if (sm != null)
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(con, con.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script, true);
        else
            con.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script, true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers a javascript file to be included in the page.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="con"></param>
    /// <param name="url"></param>
    static public void RegisterClientScriptInclude(Control con, string url)
    {
        ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(con.Page);
        if (sm != null)
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(con, con.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath + url);
        else
            con.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath + url);
    }

    public static int CurrentUserID { get { return (from u in new VAC.Data.VACDB().Users where u.UserName == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name select u.UserID).First(); } }

    public class MessageComposeEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int? SendToUserID { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        public MessageComposeEventArgs()
        {
        }

        public MessageComposeEventArgs(int SendToUserID)
        {
            this.SendToUserID = SendToUserID;
        }

        public MessageComposeEventArgs(int SendToUserID, string Subject)
        {
            this.SendToUserID = SendToUserID;
            this.Subject = Subject;
        }
    }
}
```

App_Code/ExtendedCommandField.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


/// <summary>
/// An extended <see cref="CommandField"/> that allows deletions
/// to be confirmed by the user.
/// </summary>
public class ExtendedCommandField : CommandField
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the cell.
    /// </summary>
    public override void InitializeCell(DataControlFieldCell cell,
        DataControlCellType cellType, DataControlRowState rowState, int rowIndex)
    {
        base.InitializeCell(cell, cellType, rowState, rowIndex);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DeleteConfirmationText) && this.ShowDeleteButton)
        {
            foreach (Control control in cell.Controls)
            {
                IButtonControl button = control as IButtonControl;
                if (button != null && button.CommandName == "Delete")
                    // Add delete confirmation
                    ((WebControl)control).Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format
                    ("if (!confirm('{0}')) return false;", this.DeleteConfirmationText));
            }
        }
    }

    #region DeleteConfirmationText
    /// <summary>
    /// Delete confirmation text.
    /// </summary>
    [Category("Behavior")]
    [Description("The text shown to the user to confirm the deletion.")]
    public string DeleteConfirmationText
    {
        get { return this.ViewState["DeleteConfirmationText"] as string; }
        set { this.ViewState["DeleteConfirmationText"] = value; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

~/UserControls/Messages/MessageFolder/MessageFolder.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MessageFolder.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="UserControls_Messages_MessageFolder_MessageFolder" %>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfMessageID" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="butRefresh" runat="server" Text="Check for new Messages" /><asp:Button
            ID="butCompose" runat="server" Text="Compose New Message" OnClick="butCompose_Click" /><asp:CheckBox
                AutoPostBack="true" ID="cbShowDeleted" runat="server" Text="Show Deleted Messages"
                OnCheckedChanged="cbShowDeleted_CheckChanged" />
        <asp:GridView ID="gvMessages" runat="server" DataKeyNames="MessageID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            OnRowDataBound="gvMessages_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvMessages_SelectedIndexChanged"
            OnRowDeleting="gvMessages_RowDeleting" Width="100%" Style="float: left;">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MessageID" InsertVisible="false" />
                <cc:ExtendedCommandField DeleteConfirmationText="Are you certain you wish to delete this record?"
                    DeleteText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FromUser" HeaderText="From" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ToUser" HeaderText="To" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        Sent Date</HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SentDate") %>' Style="white-space: nowrap;" /></ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" HeaderText="Subject" ItemStyle-Width="100%" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: So you are not going to E-mail?..

Comment: Nope, just inter-system messaging between users. All stored in the database.

Comment: Yeah that is a nice panel bar, however I'm thinking more of a control that has that, a quick view of all messages and a view of a single message. Oy, maybe I'll have to get off my butt and write the dang thing myself.

Comment: @BiffMaGriff can you put this project on GitHub or any public repository where we can find the whole working solution :) ? I know this is a very old post but I want to implement this in a project. It would be very nice of you

Comment: @AliUmair Asking for favours and not even bothering to give me imaginary points... this code is woefully obsolete Ali, best to just move on.

Comment: @BiffMaGriff i thought i was clear on the requirements,  i was asked for an internal messaging system for MIS i have developed. Logged in users can send each other messages which behave same as emails but they aren't emails (internal communications for registered users you can say). further email and sms alerts can be set for users when they recieve any message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own user control. If anyone is interested message and I'll post the details.

Edit:

Ok I didn't realize I wrote so much. Make sure you credit Biff_MaGriff if you use this. :D
Tech is .net 3.5 with SubSonic 3.0

Should look like this in the end.

Hmm, can't post over 30k characters...

Continued from above.

~/UserControls/Messages/MessageFolder/MessageFolder.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class UserControls_Messages_MessageFolder_MessageFolder : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IMessageFolder
{
    private static int IDCOLUMNINDEX = 0;
    private static int DELETECOLUMNINDEX = 1;
    private static int FROMCOLUMNINDEX = 2;
    private static int TOCOLUMNINDEX = 3;

    public event SelectedIndexChangedEventHandler SelectedIndexChanged;
    public delegate void SelectedIndexChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public event ComposeMessageEventHandler ComposeMessage;
    public delegate void ComposeMessageEventHandler(object sender, Common.MessageComposeEventArgs e);

    VAC.Data.VACDB db = new VAC.Data.VACDB();

    public int? MessageID
    {
        get
        {
            int id;
            if (int.TryParse(hfMessageID.Value, out id))
                return id;
            else
                return null;
        }
    }

    public CustomDataViews.MessageQuery.MailType MailType { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MailType == CustomDataViews.MessageQuery.MailType.SentMail)
        {
            butCompose.Visible = false;
        }
        Refresh();
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        gvMessages.DataSource = new CustomDataViews.MessageQuery().GetMessages(MailType, cbShowDeleted.Checked);
        gvMessages.DataBind();
        Common.HideColumn(gvMessages, IDCOLUMNINDEX);
        if (MailType == CustomDataViews.MessageQuery.MailType.ReceivedMail)
            Common.HideColumn(gvMessages, TOCOLUMNINDEX);
        else
            Common.HideColumn(gvMessages, FROMCOLUMNINDEX);
    }

    protected void gvMessages_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        Common.GridView_RowDataBound(sender, e);
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CustomDataViews.MessageQuery.Message dataItem = ((CustomDataViews.MessageQuery.Message)e.Row.DataItem);

            if (dataItem.IsDeletedSender && MailType == CustomDataViews.MessageQuery.MailType.SentMail
                || dataItem.IsDeletedRecipient && MailType == CustomDataViews.MessageQuery.MailType.ReceivedMail)
            {
                foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
                    tc.Enabled = false;
                e.Row.Cells[DELETECOLUMNINDEX].Enabled = true;
                ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[DELETECOLUMNINDEX].Controls[0]).Text = "Undelete";
                ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[DELETECOLUMNINDEX].Controls[0]).Attributes.Clear();
            }
            if (!dataItem.IsRead && MailType == CustomDataViews.MessageQuery.MailType.ReceivedMail)
            {
                //colouring for initial load
                if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Alternate) == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
                    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Common.BGColourGreenAlternate);
                else
                    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Common.BGColourGreen);
                //colouring for onmouse out
                Common.ApplyStylingToRow(e.Row, Common.SelectedBGColour(sender), Common.BGColourGreen, Common.BGColourGreenAlternate);
            }
        }

        if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).IsInAsyncPostBack && e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            Common.GridViewAddRowClick(gvMessages, e.Row, false);
    }

    protected void gvMessages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hfMessageID.Value = gvMessages.SelectedValue != null ? gvMessages.SelectedValue.ToString() : "";
        if (MailType == CustomDataViews.MessageQuery.MailType.ReceivedMail)
        {
            var mess = (from m in db.Messages where m.MessageID == MessageID.Value select m);
            if (mess.Count() == 1)
            {
                var message = mess.First();
                message.IsRead = true;
                message.Save();
            }
        }

        if (this.SelectedIndexChanged != null)
            SelectedIndexChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        this.Refresh();
    }

    protected void gvMessages_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int id;
        if (int.TryParse(((GridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[IDCOLUMNINDEX].Text, out id))
        {
            var message = (from m in db.Messages where m.MessageID == id select m).First();
            if (!message.IsDeletedRecipient && MailType == CustomDataViews.MessageQuery.MailType.ReceivedMail)
                message.IsDeletedRecipient = true;
            else
                message.IsDeletedRecipient = false;
            message.Save();

            if (!message.IsDeletedSender && MailType == CustomDataViews.MessageQuery.MailType.SentMail)
                message.IsDeletedSender = true;
            else
                message.IsDeletedSender = false;
            message.Save();

            gvMessages.SelectedIndex = -1;
            gvMessages_SelectedIndexChanged(gvMessages, new EventArgs());
        }
        Refresh();
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        Common.GridViewRowClick_Render(gvMessages);
        base.Render(writer);
    }

    protected void butCompose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ComposeMessage != null)
        {
            this.ComposeMessage(this, new Common.MessageComposeEventArgs());
        }
    }

    protected void cbShowDeleted_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

MessageCompose.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MessageCompose.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="UserControls_Messages_MessageCompose_MessageCompose" %>
<div>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="To :" />
            </td>
            <td style="width:100%">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlToUser" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="odsUsers"
                    DataTextField="UserName" DataValueField="UserID">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsUsers" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetUsers" TypeName="CustomDataViews+UserListQuery">
                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv1" runat="server" Text="*" ControlToValidate="ddlToUser"
                    ValidationGroup="Compose" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Subject :" />
            </td>
            <td style="padding: 1px 5px 1px 1px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbSubject" runat="server" Width="100%" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="padding: 1px 5px 1px 1px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbBody" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Style="width: 100%"
                    Rows="20" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMessageSentText" runat="server" Text="Your message was sent." CssClass="info" Visible="false" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Button ID="butSend" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="butSend_Click" ValidationGroup="Compose"
                                 />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

MessageCompose.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using VAC.Data;

public partial class UserControls_Messages_MessageCompose_MessageCompose : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event MessageSentEventHandler MessageSent;
    public delegate void MessageSentEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public int? SendToUserID
    {
        set
        {
            if (ddlToUser.Items.FindByValue(value.HasValue ? value.Value.ToString() : "") != null)
                ddlToUser.SelectedValue = value.HasValue ? value.Value.ToString() : "";
            else
                Common.RegisterStartupScript(this, "alert('Error :  You are unauthorized to respond to this message.');");
        }
    }

    public string SendToSubject
    {
        set
        {
            tbSubject.Text = "RE: " + value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMessageSentText.Visible = false;
    }

    private static string SENTMESSAGETEXT = "Your message was sent at {0} to {1}.";

    protected void butSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Message m = new Message();
        m.Body = tbBody.Text;
        m.FromUserID = Common.CurrentUserID;
        m.IsRead = false;
        m.SentDate = DateTime.Now;
        m.Subject = tbSubject.Text;
        int tid;
        if (int.TryParse(ddlToUser.SelectedValue, out tid))
            m.ToUserID = tid;
        m.Save();
        lblMessageSentText.Text = string.Format(SENTMESSAGETEXT, DateTime.Now.ToString(), ddlToUser.SelectedItem.Text);
        lblMessageSentText.Visible = true;

        ddlToUser.SelectedValue = null;
        tbSubject.Text = "";
        tbBody.Text = "";

        if (this.MessageSent != null)
            MessageSent(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

MessageView.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MessageView.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_Messages_MessageView_MessageView" %>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfMessageID" runat="server" />
<div style="border-style: solid;">
    <div style="font-size: x-large; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Subject") %>' /></div>
    <div style="background-color: lightblue;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="From :" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFromUser" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FromUser") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="To :" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblToUser" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ToUser") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Sent :" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSentDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SentDate") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px">
        <asp:Label ID="lblBody" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Body") %>' />
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbReply" runat="server" Text="Reply" 
            onclick="lbReply_Click" /></div>
</div>
```

MessageView.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class UserControls_Messages_MessageView_MessageView : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event ComposeMessageEventHandler ComposeMessage;
    public delegate void ComposeMessageEventHandler(object sender, Common.MessageComposeEventArgs e);

    public int? MessageID
    {
        get
        {
            int mid;
            return int.TryParse(hfMessageID.Value, out mid) ? mid : new int?();
        }
        set
        {
            hfMessageID.Value = (value.HasValue) ? value.ToString() : "";
            BindMessageView();
        }
    }

    private void BindMessageView()
    {
        if (MessageID.HasValue)
        {
            CustomDataViews.MessageQuery.Message message = new CustomDataViews.MessageQuery().GetMessage(MessageID.Value);

            this.Visible = true;
            lblBody.Text = message.Body;
            lblFromUser.Text = message.FromUser;
            lblSentDate.Text = message.SentDate.ToString();
            lblSubject.Text = message.Subject;
            lblToUser.Text = message.ToUser;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Visible = false;
            lblBody.Text = "";
            lblFromUser.Text = "";
            lblSentDate.Text = "";
            lblSubject.Text = "";
            lblToUser.Text = "";
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void lbReply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mess = (from m in new VAC.Data.VACDB().Messages where m.MessageID == MessageID select m);
        if (mess.Count() == 1)
        {
            if (this.ComposeMessage != null)
                this.ComposeMessage(this, new Common.MessageComposeEventArgs(mess.First().FromUserID, mess.First().Subject));
        }
    }
}
```

MessageBox.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MessageBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_Messages_MessageBox_MessageBox" %>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <h1>
            Message Inbox</h1>
        <cc:MessageFolder ID="mf1" runat="server" MailType="ReceivedMail" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedMessageChanged"
            OnComposeMessage="ComposeMessage" />
        <h2>
            Sent Messages</h2>
        <cc:MessageFolder ID="mf2" runat="server" MailType="SentMail" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedMessageChanged" />
        <br />
        <cc:MessageView ID="mv1" runat="server" OnComposeMessage="ComposeMessage" />
        <br />
        <cc:MessageCompose ID="mc1" runat="server" OnMessageSent="mc1_MessageSent" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

MessageBox.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class UserControls_Messages_MessageBox_MessageBox : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            mv1.MessageID = mf1.MessageID;
            mc1.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void SelectedMessageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mv1.MessageID = ((IMessageFolder)sender).MessageID;
        mc1.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void ComposeMessage(object sender, Common.MessageComposeEventArgs e)
    {
        mc1.Visible = true;
        mc1.DataBind();
        if (e.SendToUserID.HasValue)
            mc1.SendToUserID = e.SendToUserID;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Subject))
            mc1.SendToSubject = e.Subject;
    }

    protected void mc1_MessageSent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mf2.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Messages.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Templates/Patient.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Messages.aspx.cs" Inherits="UI_Patient_Messages" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <cc:MessageBox ID="mi1" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Messages.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class UI_Patient_Messages : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm interested... can you edit your answer with the details?  Thanks.

Comment: I hope that is not too overwhelming Gary.

Comment: Not at all.  It's just missing a kitchen sink!

But +1 to all your posts for effort.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to fork out some money, [Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/panelbar/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) has a nice `PanelBar` control that looks just like Outlook.  I believe the samples that ship with it are identical to the Outlook-like demo application on their site, so that would probably be a very quick and easy way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

By Steve Danner:

> Telerik has a nice PanelBar  control that looks just like Outlook. I believe the samples that ship with it are identical to the Outlook-like demo application on their site, so that would probably be a very quick and easy way to get started.

FYI, The panelbar control is just a UI, it doesn't provide the messaging functionality. Of course, you can use it to make your messaging system look like outlook, but you still have to do the coding on your own.